# How to use mysql for multiple user access by desktop application?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, pyside6

I a single user application wit PySide6 and mysql as a database. Now that my application has become bigger, i want it to be executeable by multiple users at the same time. Therefore i made 2 test users with the needed privileges.

Now when launching 2 instances of my application with 2 different users to connect to mysql, i observed that the data is not updated for both users. For example i INSERT into a table with one user and SELECT the same table with my other user, the new record is not there. Only if i close the application (and with that the mysql connection) and relaunch it, the new record is available.

From my understanding i can open the connection while starting the application and leave it open till the application is closed. Is that even right?

Are there any settings in mysql that have to be made to use it with multiple users?

--update

connecting to database on application startup

```py
    db=mysql.connector.connect(
    host= localhost,
    user= testuser,
    passwd= passwd,
    database= testschema
    )
    
    db.autocommit=False
```

example for SELECT query

```
    mycursor = db.cursor()
            
    self.SQL_String = "SELECT NR, Datum, Art, Auftraggeber, Auftrag_ID FROM auftraege"
    
    mycursor.execute(self.SQL_String)
    x = mycursor.fetchall()

    for y in x:
        #do something with the data
    
    mycursor.close()
```

example for INSERT

```
    self.SQL_String = "INSERT INTO auftraege (NR, Datum, Art, Auftraggeber) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    self.SQL_Tup = tuple(...)

    mycursor = db.cursor()

    mycursor.execute(self.SQL_String, self.SQL_Tup)
    db.commit()
        
    mycursor.close()
```

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Are you sure that you're running a single MySQL server that both users are connecting to, and not some local SQLite files?    Also, you have to keep running new SQL queries to re-read the data, the MySQL server does not automatically push data into your apps.  If you read once and cache / keep that data, the data will become stale once the other user updates the real data in MySQL.

Comment: @DaveS Yes i am running a single MySQL server to which both users are connected. I was a little bit unclear: I insert data with one user and then after that on the other user/instance I run my SELECT Query.

Comment: You need to post the code you're using for the update too. There are possible errors there that might explain what you see.

Comment: 1) timing issue: no select is executed after the insert or update 2) commit issue: modifications are commited only when the connevtion is closed. 3) isolation level issue: mysql's default isolation level is repeatable read. A select establishes a version of the data that is read by a user and subsequent selects return the same data, even if it was changed.

Comment: 4) there is no error checking and the insert / update failed or updated 0 rows.  Seeing the insert / update code might let us spot errors, but only bugs not that the incoming variables are undefined or invalid

Comment: Add a `db.commit()` after you close your SELECT cursor.

Comment: As an alternative, setting "autocommit=True" should also solve the problem, but with a small performance penalty.